# trying to get data in admin lte 3 calendar but i am facing problem on showing them in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my calendar I want to show appoinmtents for the specific date. When a user clicks on date a form would slide down and it would have details but I tried with ajax and jquery to do this. I get the data and with ajax and I tried to console log it and I did get data there but its showing same data on all dates and I haven't found any solution for this.

```
<div id="calendar" style="width: 100%" 
    @foreach($ress as $res)data-id="{{ $res->id }}" data-content="{{ $res->name }}" @endforeach 
    onclick="getDetails(this)">
</div>
```

this is where my calendar shows up

```
function getDetails(myObj) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.day').click(function () {

            var id = $(myObj).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route('get.details') }}',
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    res_id: id,
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    var response = $(res);
                    console.log(response);

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

this is my ajax function to get appointments

```
  public function getDetails(Request $request)
  {

    $response = Reservation::findOrFail($request->res_id);

    return response()->json(['success'=>'yes it works','response'=>$response]);
  }
```

This is my method in controller

What I want to happen is when I click on a date it should only bring it's appointments set by the admin and I have failed miserably in trying to do that I will be really thankful if anyone can guide me here.

Comment: I Think something wrong with your view...
why are you generating multiple attributes inside a tag with foreach?

Comment: i wanted to hvae different id for each date

Comment: you can have multiple attributes with the same name, in this case the last attribute will override other attributes value!

Comment: ok mate futher would u able to guide mw